# reducers is not being called when using --aot=true

Tags: angular, ngrx, aot

I have angular 4.4.3 project with ngrx 4.0.3 and angular-cli 1.1.2.

Everything is OK when i'm not using **aot** option, but when i'm using --aot=true I can see that reducers not being called  (because I cannot see console output 'REDUCER FIRED'):

action:

```
import { Post } from '../models';
import {Action as NgRxAction} from '@ngrx/store';
export interface Action extends NgRxAction {
    payload?: any;
}
@Injectable()
export class PostActions {
    static LOAD_POSTS = '[Post] Load Posts';
    loadPosts(): Action {
        return {
            type: PostActions.LOAD_POSTS
        };
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

effects:

```
import { AppState } from '../reducers';
import { PostActions, Action } from '../actions';
import { LoadHtmlServiceService } from '../services/load-html-service.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()
export class PostEffects {
    constructor(
        private update$: Actions,
        private postActions: PostActions,
        private svc: LoadHtmlServiceService
    ) { }

    @Effect() loadPosts$ = this.update$
        .ofType(PostActions.LOAD_POSTS)
        .switchMap(() => this.svc.getAllSections())
        .map(posts => this.postActions.loadPostsSuccess(posts));
    ...
    ... 
}
```

reducers/post-list:

```
import { PostActions, Action } from '../actions';
export type PostListState = Post[];
const initialState: PostListState = [];

export default function (state = initialState, action: Action): PostListState {
    console.log('REDUCER FIRED!!!!')
    switch (action.type) {        
        case PostActions.LOAD_POST_SUCCESS: {
            return action.payload;
        }
       ...
       ...
    }
}
```

reducers/index:

```
import postListReducer, * as fromPostList from './post-list';
import postReducer, * as fromPost from './post';
import userReducer, * as fromUser from './user';

export interface AppState {
    posts: fromPostList.PostListState;
    post: fromPost.PostState;
    user: fromUser.UserState;
};


export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
   posts: postListReducer,
   post: postReducer,
   user: userReducer
};
```

app.module:

```
 import { reducers } from './reducers';
 import { PostEffects } from './effects';
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
   AppComponent
 ],
  entryComponents: [AddSectionModalComponent],
  imports: [
    LayoutModule
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([PostEffects])
  ]
...
...
```

Is Where something I forgot?

Thanks good ngrx peolpe

Answer (score 2):

finally figured out how to make my code run wit --aot:

The trick was:

1. defining injectionToken on **reducers/index**:

   ```
   export const reducerToken = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<AppState>>('Registered Reducers');         
   Object.assign(reducerToken, reducers);
   ```
2. define getReducers factory(**app.module**):

   ```
   export function getReducers() {
     return reducers;
   }
   ```
3. when registering modules on **app.module**:
   register reducerToken and provide it in provders section:

   ```
   imports:[   
      ...
      ...
      StoreModule.forRoot(reducerToken),
      EffectsModule.forRoot([PostEffects])
   ],
    providers: [
   {
      provide: reducerToken,
      useFactory: getReducers
   }
   ```